# How to delete woocommerce customers / users from shop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was wondering how to easily delete registered users / customers from my woocommerce online shop.

Most solutions centered around running a SQL code, which really isn't as handy.

However, after a bit research I finally found a very easy solution - see answer below.

Hope it helps you too!

Cheers
David

Answer (score -2):

Every customer that registers via the woocommerce registration process, is added as a wordpress user, so you can delete users / customers super easily there.

**1. go to your wp admin**

**2. left side click "users"**

**3. delete the users / customers**